# MMB now triggers popup warning

Tags: google-chrome

I'm on Version 71.0.3578.98 and think I have been on that version for some time now, I doubt that it upgraded today.

Since today I have a very strange issue. I'm a heavy MMB (middle mouse button) user to pre-open+load links which I will read in a couple of seconds/minutes.

Now, when I MMB-click on any link, be it on www.google.com, stackexchange.com, it is as if it causes the tab to be opened in a popup; at least I'm getting the popup warning where I can then add an exclusion for the domain. When I add the exclusion, then I can use MMB to open links like I've been doing as usual.

What could be causing this? Maybe an extension which started to intercept those clicks and then faking them?

Comment: If you backup your Chrome user profile, delete the current profile, does the behavior continue to happen?

Comment: Good point. I just started another instance with another profile and there it works. It's probably an extension.